# How to verify response of any Http Request is valid JSON or not?

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, httpresponse

Suppose i have a Http request in json/xml when i post this request then we get some JSON response, then First i need to verify  this response is valid json or not in java.how to do that in one go?

Comment: do you mean valid or well formed, the 2 are different

Answer (score 0):

A wild idea, try parsing it and catch the exception:

```
public boolean isJSONValid(String test) {
    try {
        new JSONObject(test);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {

        // e.g. in case JSONArray is valid as well...
        try {
            new JSONArray(test);
        } catch (JSONException ex1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain why?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Deserialize, if it passes the Deserialize so it's a valid Json, if your Json is not valid it will return a Exception for you, try something like this:

```
  //I'm using proxy with this request
  RESTResponse response = await WebServiceProxy.GetInstance().Request(connection);

           //Check if the response is a OK
            if (response.statusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

                try
                {
                    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.content);

                 } catch(Exception ex) {  }
            }
```